# How to display the output of a form?

Tags: forms

I created a custom module which contains a form with submit button.
After connecting to the data base I have an output table that contain the result.

The question is that I can't display and show this table(`$output`) in the main content page

I used  `drupal_set_message($output);` in

But I want to display the result in the body of the page.

function form_test_menu() {
  $items['formtest'] = array(
    'title' => 'Form test',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
     'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' =>array('form_test_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    );
  return $items;
}
function form_test_form($form,&$form_submit) {

$form = array();
 $form['#multistep'] = TRUE;

$form['search'] = array(
    '#title' =>t('search'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
   // '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['fromdate'] = array( 
     '#type' => 'date_popup',
     '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
     '#title' => "from " 
   ); 
  $form['todate'] = array(
    '#title' => t('to'),
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
     '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#type' => 'submit',

);

if(!empty($form_state['results_table'])){
  $form['results_table'] = array('#markup'=>$form_state['results_table']);

}
  return $form;
}
 function form_test_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
       drupal_set_message(t('in'));
      $form_state['storage']['values'] = $form_state['values'] ;
     $search = $form_state['values']['search']; 
      drupal_set_message($search);
          $todt=$form_state['values']['todate']; 
     $begindt=$form_state['values']['fromdate']; 
    $search_terms = explode(' ', $search);
       drupal_set_message($todt);
db_set_active('my_other_db');
$query = db_select('karar', 'f');
if (empty($search)&!empty($todt) &!empty($begindt)){

$query 
->fields('f', array('type','subject','date'))
->condition('f.date',$todt,'<=')
->condition('f.date',$begindt,'>=');

```
    }
```

else if (empty($todt) & empty ($begindt) & !empty($search)){
    foreach($search_terms as $search_term){
   $query->condition('f.subject','%'. db_like($search_term) . '%', 'LIKE')
   ->fields('f', array('type', 'subject','date'));
  drupal_set_message($search_term);

}
        }
 else if (empty($todt) & !empty ($begindt) & ! empty ($search)){

```
$query
```

->condition('f.date',$begindt,'>=');

foreach($search_terms as $search_term){
   $query->condition('f.subject','%'. db_like($search_term) . '%', 'LIKE')
   ->fields('f', array('type', 'subject','date'));
  drupal_set_message($search_term);
}
drupal_set_message("begin + kelmeh w ana e5deh el last today");
}
else if (!empty ($search) & !empty ($todt) & !empty($begindt)){
$query 
->condition('f.date',$todt,'<=')
->condition('f.date',$begindt,'>=')
->fields('f', array('type', 'subject','date'));
foreach($search_terms as $search_term){
   $query->condition('f.subject','%'. db_like($search_term) . '%', 'LIKE');
  drupal_set_message($search_term);
}

}

else {
     db_set_active();
      form_set_error('keys', t('Please enter some keywords.'));
drupal_set_message(t(''),'error');
return;
}
drupal_set_message(t('after return'));
$result = $query->execute();

```
  $header = array('year', 'subj','hist');
  $rows = array();

  while($data = $result->fetchObject()){
         $rows[] = array(
          $data->type,
          $data->subject,
          $data->date,
                    );
  }
  $output = theme_table(
        array(
          "header" => $header,
          "rows" => $rows,
          "attributes" => array(),
          "sticky" => true, // Table header will be sticky
          "caption" => "",
          "colgroups" => array(),
          "empty" => t("Table has no data!") // The message to be displayed if table is empty
        )
  );

    $variables = array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows);
$content = theme('table', $variables, array());
db_set_active();
 $form_state['results_table'] = $output;
 $form_state['storage']['results_table']=$output;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  return $form;
```

}

but nothing is displayed
any help

Comment: what do you mean by main content page?

Comment: There is two ways to display it in content area:
1) If you created the form from the block then please assign it in the region "main content"
2) If you created this from custom page means hook_menu, then see your page.tpl.php structure whether the "main content" region is assign in the right place.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Since the question is about code, we would need to see it. Plus, we cannot write the code for a form submission handler to show its output, nor we cannot describe you exactly how to do it; the topic is too broad, also because we don't know what you understand about Drupal form API.

Comment: i create a module that read from database and display the result in a TABLE. I Am not able to display the table

Comment: You can edit the template.php in your themes folder ( sites/all/themes/YOUR_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE ) and in the `YOUR_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE_preprocess_function´  add the call to your module function, like this: `$variables["page"]["content"]= your_function()` . If you need your result to appear only in a node, then you can previously identify your node by its nid: if ($variables["node"]->nid == YOUR_NID ) { $variables["page"]["content"]= your_function() }

Comment: @Cesar That is the wrong way: A module outputs its pages by its own. Do you see the Bartik theme calling each module's function to let them print their output? I think not.

Comment: Well, that way works, so I wouldn't call it wrong way. You can also try the following approach, as suggested by kiamlaluno, but it has its own problems:     function yourmodule_menu(){
 $items['mypage/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => "_myfunction",
    'page arguments' => array(3),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
     'access callback' => TRUE,
);

Comment: @Cesar _has its own problems_? Then, every core module has those problems, but I find difficult to believe it. In Drupal, a theme doesn't call a module function to make its output appear. It could work, but it's not the way Drupal code should be written, and there are surely issues with that way of writing code. First at all, you should need to edit a Drupal core theme for every module you add, if all the modules would follow that approach.

Comment: Well, for example by using the Domain Access module to show a page in certain domains and languages, it is better to have the pages as nodes instead of being created by the module. And like that example, there are many. In the end, for a big project I had to mix both approaches, the standard way for autocomplete, forms, etc., and the other way for showing some filtered content and displaying different templates in complex contexts - not using Panels, etc. Template calling module function is strange, but had to move function from template.php to mymodule.module to get it working globally.